# Will Music apps like Saavn be on background or foreground when they are playing in Notification Bar?

Tags: android, notifications

I wanted to know whether music apps when they are playing in Notification Bar, is the app running in background or foreground.

Comment: This question is very broad, opinion-based, and doesn't involve any code. Not fit for S/O!

Answer (score 2):

I've recently built an Android music player app which played music on background. I this is the case for all music player apps. You can refer to this tutorial if you need any assistance

First part: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-music-player-on-android-project-setup--mobile-22764
Second part: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-music-player-on-android-song-playback--mobile-22778
Third part: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-music-player-on-android-user-controls--mobile-22787